# Getting the ID of a parent table before inserting child record in a Table-per-Type Inheritance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a parent Table named Technology with the following main fields (TechnologyID, TechnologyTypeID, timestamp,etc).

Then I have inheritance-per type tables such as Rack, server, VM,PC ,etc. where the ID of each child table is also a foreign key to the TechnologyID insdie the parent table.

Now I have the following action method to add new Rack:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Server server)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {

                repository.InsertOrUpdateServer(server);
                repository.Save();

return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
else {
return View();
            }
        }
```

But the above will raise an exception, since the RACKID which is the table PK & FK is null. So my question is how I can add a new instance of the parent table(Technology) and get its ID ,then assign this ID to the server before saving it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Get some reference/id for the `technology` object in which you are going to add `server`/`rack` as a child.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Server server, int technologyID)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {

                var technology = repository.Technologies.Where(t => t.Id == technologyID).FirstOrDefault();
                server.technologyId = technology.Id;
                repository.InsertOrUpdateServer(server);
                repository.Save();

return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
else {
return View();
            }
    }
```

Comment: but when adding new server i will be adding  the related technology record, so no TechnologyId will be their to retrieve ...

Comment: I think I misunderstood you on this. Are you not saying that the Technology is the parent table and the Server/Rack are childs?

Comment: yes , when adding a new server i will automatically create a new technology record , get its tehnologyID and then add new server with the technologyID as PF.

Comment: Ok, here is a suggestion. Show a list of existing technologies' names to the user or ask for a new name from him, then modify your action's signature like this `public ActionResult Create(Server server, string technologyName)` or you showing the list of existing technologies then change it to `public ActionResult Create(Server server, int technologyId)`. Then in the body, first save the technology then rack/server.

Comment: Actually there are no fields inside the Technology table that is user defined , it contains only ID, timestamp, created date , etc.